# Why my heap read/heap hit ratio is negative?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, django

I have a database with 200k rows (one of this column is a jsonb data type column), i'm using this database to store some various devices informations (currents, pressure, etc...) and i'm using this table to get the respective measurements of a specific device using a time range. When the database is small (like 50/70k rows) everything works fine, the cache hit ratio is positive and around the 99%.

When the database grows, like now, the cache hit ratio will decrease dramaticaly and goes to negative, as shown below:

[image]

But, as you can see, the index on the table it seems to be in a good state (despite the low number of rows contained in the index):

[image]

The database size is around 200MB and the modbus table has the size of 156Mb, my host has a 1GB Ram with 2CPU.

Here there is one of the slowest query, for only 54/60 results, it gives 10 seconds of execution:

[image]

Please, give me some advices...

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide your queries as text and give us the output for an `explain analyze` ?

Comment: Here is the Explain of the query and the query itself:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/7jrN

https://pastebin.com/Yk3fGabQ

Comment: @Arkhena, did you noticed something strange in my query?

Comment: Well, what I see is that query took less than 250ms, could you provide the plan when it takes 10s ?

Comment: I'll give to you the query, but, in any case, this query it's optimized in your opinion?

Comment: First optimization rule : don't do it. Second optimization rule : don't do it yet (for experts only). If your query runs under 250ms, it probably doesn't need optimization.

Comment: ...@Arkhena, i think that i've found the issue: my django app, actually it's doing a query (with the selection of the json key) for every datapoint, i mean, if i have ten datapoint (ex.: VLN1, VLN2, VLN3, IL1, IL2, IL3, PL1, PL2, PL3, etc...) my code will execute a query with the respective subselect for each of them: this is extremely inefficient.
Now i'm working to do a single query with much sub-select as the number of my datapoints, in order to execute only one query. i think that the problem is definitively this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89237/discussion-between-arkhena-and-virtapp).